# React setState don't update values inside a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, airtable

I'm trying to store data with my setState method inside my function but it never update it, however if I set them to a variable (I call it "x") it works.

I have my function which returns a Promise

I hope I can get help figuring out where I went wrong or understand if it cannot be done or not.

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAirtable } from "../functions/useAirtable";
import { MyType } from "../model/MyType";

const Foo: NextPage = () => {

  const [barbaz, setBarbaz] = useState<any>([]);
  let x: any = [];

  try {
    useAirtable("My_Table").then((data: MyType) => {

        setBarbaz(data);
        x = data;

        console.log("print1: ", data); //It PRINTS data
        console.log("print2: ", barbaz); //It PRINTS empty array
        console.log("print3: ", x); //It PRINTS data
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {}

  console.log("print4: ", barbaz); //It PRINTS empty array
  console.log("print5: ", x); //It PRINTS empty array

  return <div> where is waldo </div>;
};

export default Foo;
```

Comment: `barbaz` isn't being assigned to until the next call to `useState` is reached - you're closed over the _previous_ value.

Comment: `useAirtable` sounds like it's a react hook. If that's the case most likely don't need the extra state variable to get the API data. I would suggest revisiting the documentation because this code looks like it would trigger an infinite loop

Comment: `try { somecode } catch (error) {}`    You could have an error message that would have really helped, but for some reason you have created a black hole to catch them.

Comment: @AbirTaheer ok, but if so, can you tell me how I can access to my "x" variable outside the try catch after I assign it the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your async call on a `useEffect` hook.

```js
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAirtable } from "../functions/useAirtable";
import { MyType } from "../model/MyType";

const Foo: NextPage = () => {

  const [barbaz, setBarbaz] = useState<any>([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    useAirtable("My_Table").then((data: MyType) => {
      setBarbaz(data);
    }
  }, [])

  return <div> where is waldo </div>;
};

export default Foo;
```

Comment: This looks like it might be the issue, if so, the OP has named the function rather bad.. :)